# __import__() calls __init__.py twice?

Tags: python

I was just wondering why `__import__()` calls a `__init__` module twice when loading a package.

```
test.py
testpkg/
        __init__.py
```

**`test.py`:**

```
pkg = __import__("testpkg", fromlist=[''])
```

**`__init__.py`:**

```
print "Called."
```

After calling `python test.py`, *Called.* will be printed out twice. Why does python execute the `__init__` "module" twice?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on Python 2.6.5. Which version are you using? Are you sure this is the complete code you posted there?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.4. The two lines of code is all I'm using to reproduce. I've just tried with Python 2.4.3, I get the same results.

Comment: I get it on python 2.6.5 on linux2 built with g.c.c 4.4.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Python bug.  Passing the null string as an element of `fromlist` is illegal, and should raise an exception.

There's no need to include `""` in `fromlist`; that's implicit--the module itself is always loaded.  What's actually happening is the `module.submodule` string is using the null string, resulting in the module name `testpkg.`, with a trailing period.  That gets imported literally, and since it has a different name than `testpkg`, it's imported as a separate module.

Try this:

```
pkg = __import__("testpkg", fromlist=[''])
import sys
print sys["testpkg"]
print sys["testpkg."]
```

... and you'll see the duplicate module.

Someone should probably file a ticket on this if there isn't already one; too tired to do it myself right now.

Comment: Note: happens for me in Python 2.6.4 and 3.1.1.  If you do file a bug, please be sure it's not already fixed in newer versions first.

Comment: there was already ticket 2090 for python 2.7 but i didn't see any message of the versions mentioned on this page so I added a comment.

Comment: You are right. After replacing [''] by an empty list, the `__init__` module is only called once. Just fixed the SO-Answer I copied this code from.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `fromlist=['']` hack to import a specific module is explicitly frowned upon by python-dev. While it has been [filed as an issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue2090), the chances of it being fixed are low specifically because this is viewed as a mis-use of `fromlist` to begin with instead of necessarily a bug and a better solution is available.

What you should be doing is using `importlib.import_module` (available in the standard library for Python 2.7 and Python 3.1, or from PyPI with compatibility back to Python 2.3 along with being included in Django since 1.1 as `django.utils.importlib`). It will prevent this problem from happening, provides a better programmatic interface for importing modules, and even lets you use relative imports when you specify the package you are importing from.

If you **really** cannot use importlib (e.g., PyPI dependencies are not allowed even though the code you can freely copy thanks to the PSF license and it being rather short), then you should be doing `__import__("some.module"); mod = sys.modules["some.module"]`. That is the official, python-dev sanctioned solution to the problem (but only **after** you cannot use `importlib`).